# how to reverse ul li javascript asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a ul li menu im using english version and arabic version. Now when in arabic version the menu must be in reverse order how can we acheive that my code is

```
 <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="../Default.aspx">
            <img src="../images/logoheader.png" height="24px" alt="Home" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="../Lgs.aspx?confirm=1">
            <%=Resources.Fields.lgs%></a> </li>
        <li><a href="../CustomPage.aspx?Pid=2">
            <%=Resources.Fields.aboutus%></a> </li>
        <li><a href="../Login.aspx?confirm=1">
            <%=Resources.Fields.login%>
        </a><a href="../Signup.aspx?confirm=1">
            <%=Resources.Fields.register%></a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">
                <%=Resources.Fields.more_new%></a></li>
    </ul>
```

this will show like this 
Home |  Lgs | AboutUs | Login | Signup | More

i want to reverse it like this in javascript

More | Signup | Login | Aboutus | Lgs | Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add jquery and use following in the body

```
 ul = $('#menu'); // your parent ul element
ul.children().each(function(i,li){ul.prepend(li)});
```

Comment: Please don't give jQuery answers to non-jQuery questions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Why not. It is not in my opinion down-voting time, perhaps OP did not consider jQuery when asking

Comment: @mplungjan: You don't know that I downvoted, just that I commented. The two *frequently* do not travel together. (I did this time, granted, but I frequently comment without DV.)

Comment: Right. Still in this case using jQuery may be an option. It IS JavaScript anyway :)

Comment: @mplungjan: From the above: *"You will **have to** add jquery..."* (my emphasis). I knew there was a reason I didn't just comment. :-)

Comment: @mplungjan it is not just JavaScript, it's overhead and another dependency which you are adding for something that can be resolved without it and most probably faster too.

Comment: I agree - I am the first to mention plain JS when jQuery is not needed. However if jQuery is used elsewhere on the page or something is just immensely simpler in jQuery, I prefer the overhead which is about the size of a small logo.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to output the `li` elements in the appropriate order server-side.

But if you want to handle it client-side: You don't need JavaScript for this unless you need to support IE7 or earlier.

Several client-side options for you:

1. The HTML `dir` attribute *(doesn't work on IE7 and earlier, works on IE8 and up)*
2. CSS's `direction: rtl` *(doesn't work on IE7 and earlier, works on IE8 and up)*
3. JavaScript *(works even on IE6)*

#### 1. The HTML `dir` attribute

You can use the `dir` attribute on the `ul`:

```
<ul id="menu" dir="RTL">
```

If the `li` elements are `inline-block`, that will reverse the order of them.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/1/edit)

I would recommend applying that attribute server-side, before the page goes out, but if you need to do it in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("menu").dir = "RTL";
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/2/edit)

#### 2. CSS

You can also do it by applying CSS:

```
#menu {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/3/edit)

#### 3. JavaScript

But the JavaScript solution would be to walk through the list items in order, starting with the second one, and move each of them to the top using the `insertBefore` DOM method. You end up with the order reversed. Looks like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("menu");
var child, sibling;

if (list.childNodes.length > 1) {
  for (child = list.firstChild.nextSibling; child; child = sibling) {
    sibling = child.nextSibling;
    list.insertBefore(child, list.firstChild);
  }
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/4) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ejagen/4/edit)

---

All of the above adjust the order of the `li` elements but not the direction of the text within them, I assume you're handling that elsewhere. But if you aren't, just apply this CSS to any element you want to make RTL instead of LTR:

```
relevant_selector {
  direction:rtl;
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}
```

Comment: @skhurams: Which "it"? There are 3 or 4 solutions above depending on how you want to count. :-) And which version(s) of IE do you need to support? I've done some checks, looks like the RTL solutions don't work on IE7 and earlier (quelle shock), but do on IE8 and IE9. The JavaScript solution works everywhere. And of course, outputting the `li` elements in the appropriate order server-side would work regardless of browser. :-)

Comment: @skhurams: Good deal, glad that helped!